# SQLite: How to avoid using two CTE when using CASE statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite, case, common-table-expression

I have a table `trx` with following schema:

```
| id   | p_id |
| 1    | 1    |
| 2    | 1    |
| 3    | 4    |
...
| 1000 | 2    |
```

where `id` is the transaction id and `p_id` the id of the person doing it.

I need to query `trx` so I get a table that allows me to plot an histogram of frequencies of transactions, that means, I want to know how many `p_id` did only 1 transaction, how many did 2, and so on. I have to aggregate 11 and more transactions in a `+10` bin:

```
| n_trx | bin_size |
| 1     | 10       |
| 2     | 18       |
| 3     | 7        |
...
| +10   | 26       |
```

I know that I need the `CASE` statement for the `+10` thing, and I approached the task using two `CTE`:

```
WITH new_trx_history
     AS (WITH trx_history
              AS (SELECT p_id,
                         Count(DISTINCT id) AS n_trx
                  FROM   trx
                  GROUP  BY p_id)
         SELECT CASE
                  WHEN n_trx < 11 THEN n_trx
                  ELSE '+10'
                END      AS n_trx,
                Count(*) AS bin_size
          FROM   trx_history
          GROUP  BY n_trx)
SELECT n_trx,
       Sum(bin_size)
FROM   new_trx_history
GROUP  BY n_trx;
```

I would like to know if there is **a way to have a more direct approach** than my actual *(working)* query.

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/40f887/4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` in `GROUP BY`

```
     WITH trx_history
          AS (SELECT p_id,
                     Count(DISTINCT id) AS n_trx
              FROM   trx
              GROUP  BY p_id)
     SELECT CASE
              WHEN n_trx < 11 THEN n_trx
              ELSE '+10'
            END      AS n_trx,
            Count(*) AS bin_size
      FROM   trx_history
      GROUP  BY CASE
              WHEN n_trx < 11 THEN n_trx
              ELSE '+10'
            END
      ;
```

Comment: I was not aware that you could use case for grouping! But it looks cool!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without any CTE if you use of `COUNT()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >= 10 THEN '+10' ELSE COUNT(*) END AS n_trx,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CASE WHEN COUNT(*) >= 10 THEN '+10' ELSE COUNT(*) END) AS bin_size
FROM trx
GROUP BY p_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e3d0c10853923ac649a47935b89a43c2).
Results:

```
n_trx | bin_size
----- | --------
    3 |        1
    6 |        1
  +10 |        3
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend writing the query like this:

```
WITH p as (
     SELECT p_id,
            Count(*) AS n_trx
     FROM trx
     GROUP BY p_id
    )
SELECT (CASE WHEN n_trx < 11 THEN n_trx
             ELSE '+10'
        END) AS trx_grp,
       Count(*) AS bin_size
FROM p
GROUP BY trx_grp
ORDER BY MIN(n_trx);
```

Notes:

1. You don't seem to need `COUNT(DISTINCT)` for the CTE.  The `id`s look unique in the transaction table and `COUNT(DISTINCT)` incurs extra overhead.
2. You can aggregate by a column alias in SQLite.  However, it is better if it has a different name from any columns in the `FROM` clause.
3. You can easily order using an aggregation function.
4. SQLite allows you to mix the types in the `CASE` expression.  That is due to its arcane handling of types.  Any other SQL dialect would convert `'+10'` to the number `10`.